# Usar o Angular 2 sem o NodeJS depois do build

Tags: node.js, angular

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em **Angular 2** usando **Webpack**.

Minhas dúvidas são, depois que fizer build pra produção:

- Consigo rodar esse app sem o **NodeJS** ?
- Consigo rodar o app **Angular 2** sem nenhum servidor, direto no navegador ?
- Caso precise usar algum servidor, posso usar outros como o **TomCat** ?

Comment: Sim, sim e sim. Na hora que você gera o build ele te da um index.html e o resto em javascript :)

Answer (score 1):

Bom, pra isso existe o `Angular-cli`. Ele tem uma função chamada `ǹg build`, onde ele mesmo administra o webpack para gerar os arquivos minificados ideais para a produção.

Fazendo isso, você pode rodar o build dessa aplicação em um servidor simples (apache ou nginx) sem ter dor de cabeça ou uma pasta node_modules super pesada pra que ele funcione.

Answer (score 0):

**Consigo rodar esse app sem o NodeJS ?**

> Se rodar seria desenvolver creio que nao, mas depois de terminado vc
>   pode usar o comando ng build e com isso sera gerado seus arquivos
>   compilados a partir dai não precisa mais.

**Consigo rodar o app Angular 2 sem nenhum servidor, direto no navegador ?**

> Nao, precisa de um servidor vc pode usar qualquer um [aqui](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration) tem uma
>   lista dos mais comuns.

**Caso precise usar algum servidor, posso usar outros como o TomCat ?**

> Sim como respondi acima.